# Name of a small state west of the Xiongnu and south of Wusun c. 50 A.D

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-china, steppe-nomads, mongolia, central-asia

There was a very small state in Western Mongolia which played a part in the politics of ancient Mongolia, circa 50 A.D. It sounded something like Wu-Shan-Mu or Wu-Shi-Mu. During a war between the Xiongnu (50 B.C. or A.D.?) it backed a certain faction, or the Northern or Southern Xiongnu. I think it was in the [Altai?] mountains, or up against them. It may have given princesses or consorts. It may have been connected with Kangju.

What was it?

Added: This was on Wikipedia, not too long ago. It had to do with a Xiongnu civil war or a war between the North and South Xiongnu. I seem to remember 50s or 60s as a date. I think I might confusing the roles, and "Wu Shi Mu" may have received help from Xiongnu. I am going to look over the individual Wiki pages for the Xiongnu rulers of this era. It was probably some type of tributary of Kangju in the mountains.

Comment: There's no such state during such a time. You need to be more specific - what's the exact name, or where are you getting your information?

Comment: Chanyu was a title used by Xiongnu leaders

Comment: Sources would *greatly* improve this answer.  You clearly have some sources/information about this small state; you have a reason to believe it exists.  But you're forcing us to search blindly without any context.   Rather than a serious historical question, this reads like, "I'm thinking of a number..."  Can you provide sufficient context to help us help you?

Comment: It seems like you are describing [Kangju](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangju)

Answer (score 1):

I found it in my notes. It's called Wu-Shan-Mu. Curiously, "Wu Shan Mu Xiongnu" brought up no results on google.
"Wu-shan-mu had close ties with the Hsiung-nu. Hu-lu-ku, ruler of the Hsiungnu (96–85 b.c.), arranged a marriage with the family of the ruler of the Wu-shan-mu, establishing blood ties between the two states. In 60 b.c. Ch’i-hou-shan, son of the ruler of the Hsiung-nu, having failed to inherit the throne, fled to the court of his father-in-law in
Wu-shan-mu, who played a decisive role in the election of Ch’i-hou-shan to the position of ruler of the Southern Hsiung-nu in 58 b.c., at the time of the division of the Hsiungnu into two mutually hostile kingdoms. Wu-shan-mu, a minor power, could have played such a role only with the support of a Hsiung-nu military force." p. 459
http://en.unesco.org/silkroad/sites/silkroad/files/knowledge-bank-article/vol_II%20silk%20road_the%20nomads%20of%20northern%20central%20asia%20after%20the%20invansion%20of%20alexander.pdf